# Execution failed for task Program type already present

Tags: android

I include this new library into my dependencies

```
compile 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'
```

Then when I build I get build error

```
Error:Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_458" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\kepler\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
```

Is it possible I have a dependency conflict according from above message?

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl
```

I've tried printing my dependency tree, but I have no idea how to find the dependency conflict with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try switching

```
compile 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'`
```

If that doesn't work try excluding the support library from the new package

```
implementation('com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1') { exclude group: 'com.android.support' }
```

Comment: Well gee thanks, I wish **I** had thought of using "exclude group"