# org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, gradle, google-play-services

I have exported my Unity project to Android Studio project. I wanted to add Firebase Messaging to my project through Studio, since Firebase Messaging implemented in unity was not working.

So I added the following code to my `app/build.gradle` which is causing me all these problems.

```
dependencies {
.
.
.
compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
}

buildscript {
.
.
.
dependencies {
   .
   .
   .
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have added `google-services.json` file to app directory.

If I comment most of the aar dependencies from `build.gradle`, the app will build successfully without any errors. But the Firebase analytics which I am using in my project won't work.

While building the app I am getting following errors.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
and
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/66.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/68.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/69.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/70.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/71.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/72.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/73.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/80.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/82.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/83.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/84.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/85.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/86.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/87.jar
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/66.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/68.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/69.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/70.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/71.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/72.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/73.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/80.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/82.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/83.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/84.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/85.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/86.jar, /Users/nabeelkottol/Downloads/VR DEVOTEE 2/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/87.jar
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:109)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:123)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 123 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:88)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    ... 131 more
```

and

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I believe this is happening due to duplication of dependencies. I don't have enough knowledge on gradle to find out that particular package and exclude from building. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

My `build.gradle` is as given below:

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'
    }
    google()
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile(name: 'androidnative', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-compat-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-ui-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-utils-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-fragment-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-media-compat-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-v4-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-unity-4.4.1', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-app-unity-4.4.1', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-core-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'exoplayer-r1.5.11', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'gvr-exoplayersupport-release', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'gvr_android_common', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'installreferrer-1.0', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'kalpnikutilitylibrary-release', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'mobile-native-popups', ext: 'aar')
  compile(name: 'unitygvractivity', ext: 'aar')
  compile project(':Firebase')
  compile project(':answers')
  compile project(':beta')
  compile project(':crashlytics')
  compile project(':crashlytics-wrapper')
  compile project(':fabric')
  compile project(':fabric-init')
  compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 27
    applicationId 'applicationId'
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }

  aaptOptions {
    noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
  }


  buildTypes {
    debug {
      jniDebuggable true
    }
    release {
      // Set minifyEnabled to true if you want to run ProGuard on your project
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: sorry. its not working

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56993319/8995811

Answer (score 3):

I could not test the `build.gradle` that I have prepared. However, I think the following gradle should work.

Let me put things that I have added in your gradle.

`DexArchiveMergerException` is mostly caused for not having `multidexEnabled true`. I have added the attribute.

Moved the `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to the top.

Added `javaMaxHeapSize "4g"` in the `dexOptions` section. Added `resolutionStrategy` in case of multiple version of the same library is found along with a `packagingOption`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        google()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 27
        applicationId 'applicationId'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            // Set minifyEnabled to true if you want to run ProGuard on your project
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
        }
    }
}

android.packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'androidnative', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-compat-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-ui-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-utils-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-fragment-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-media-compat-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-v4-25.2.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-unity-4.4.1', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-app-unity-4.4.1', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-core-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-license-11.8.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'exoplayer-r1.5.11', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'gvr-exoplayersupport-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'gvr_android_common', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'installreferrer-1.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'kalpnikutilitylibrary-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'mobile-native-popups', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'unitygvractivity', ext: 'aar')
    compile project(':Firebase')
    compile project(':answers')
    compile project(':beta')
    compile project(':crashlytics')
    compile project(':crashlytics-wrapper')
    compile project(':fabric')
    compile project(':fabric-init')
    compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If the issues are not resolved, please try enabling your application as a `MultiDexApplication` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3145960).

Please let me know if you get any further error or different type of error.

Comment: thanks. let me try. but I think gms is causing the issue. how can I add that to resolution strategy.

Comment: Please see the update and let me know if the problem still persists.

Comment: I have enabled MultiDExApplication as well. but nothing changed.

Comment: I think main issue is `Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver`. DEx related issue is occuring because of this. if I remove firebase dependency project runs without issues. but I need that to show bigpicture notification. since its not supported in Unity.

Comment: The issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103842/3145960) as well. I have updated the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

**Can you change this and try**

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 27
    applicationId 'applicationId'
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }

  aaptOptions {
    noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
  }


  buildTypes {
    debug {
      jniDebuggable true
    }
    release {
      // Set minifyEnabled to true if you want to run ProGuard on your project
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }
  }
}
```

**to**

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 27
    applicationId 'applicationId'
  }

  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }

  aaptOptions {
    noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
  }


  buildTypes {
    debug {
      jniDebuggable true
      multiDexEnabled true
    }
    release {
      // Set minifyEnabled to true if you want to run ProGuard on your project
      multiDexEnabled true
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }
  }
}
```

**Then, on the AndroidManifest.xml add this**

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
...
</application>
```

Comment: have you try the application class also? and also you can add this in gradle and try `compile(name: 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3, ext: 'aar')`